# Serving json documents directly from couchdb

Tags: database, web-applications, couchdb

I'm wondering if serving documents from couchDB directly is an actual typical real world scenario, or if most people use it inside server code (as with traditional databases) and then serve from there ?

I find couchDB pretty interesting but wonder how to integrate the database access with normal web scenarios.. there isn't so much experience and literature out on that yet seemingly.

(Yes, I know that I have to use a proxy anyway, I'm just curious how it is typically integrated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CouchDB book "CouchDB the definitive guide" goes in detail into this. There is also CouchApp which is a framework to create web-apps using nothing else than a Couchdb server.

But I do not know if someone uses it in production (with someone I mean : a Big Gun, that it has crossed over the early adopters chasm).

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into that. Do you know if it is in line with the current versions ?

Comment: I just finished it and I did all the exercises using CouchDB 1.0.1 . There are some really minor cosmetic differences but everything just worked as expected. I did see some real differences using the couchapp example though, the sofa application as currently available from sofa has moved on a lot from the example of the book.

Answer (score 1):

[CouchApp](http://github.com/jchris/couchapp) provides some convenient tools for serving web apps directly from CouchDB. If your needs fit in the CouchApp model, it's very convenient and quite enjoyable.